# My Custom Module is redirecting to 404 page in Magento2 CR2

Tags: magento2

I develop one custom module but its redirecting to 404 page and also it not create my custom table (once i run upgrade cli it will make entry in config.php and set) but its work fine on beta version 
below are the i used please correct me where i did mistakes 

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sugarcode_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\composer.json

```
{
    "name": "sugarcode/module-test",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-store": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-cms": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Sugarcode\\Test\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sugarcode_Test" setup_version="2.0.6" />
</config>
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Sugarcode_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
/**
 * Default customer account page
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    echo 'Hello'; exit;
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
```

}

i exit in action but its not exiting it show 404 error page

url is domin.com/test

can any one help me on this

Comment: have you remove cache and generation folder from var?

Comment: This is a known problem in Magento2 RC2, see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2381 for details (wrong composer.json generated at build of RC2)

Comment: @RBJesadiya i did it but no luck

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff:- thanks so i need to wait till next release

Comment: have you checked your module is enable in admin? Have you run command setup:upgrade using cli.

Comment: @RBJesadiya :- this is magneto release bug we need to wait for next version release please check on  github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2381